# SQL Server Order By - tricky

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

```
SortOrder     FundType
9              DD
2              DD
13             FF
22             BB
11             FF
```

I want to group by FundType and then Order By SortOrder. But I want to maintain this order w/ respect to FundType: DD, FF, BB

So I want the final output to look like:

```
SortOrder  FundType
2           DD
9           DD
11          FF
13          FF
22          BB
```

I cannot to an Order By FundType DESC, SortOrder because then FF will appear first and I cannot do an Order By FundType, SortOrder because then BB will appear first.

How can I set up a query where I specify the order of FundType, and then apply an Order By within each FundType grouping? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to calculate the order of each group:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT FundType, MIN(SortOrder) AS GroupOrder
   FROM #mytable
   GROUP BY FundType
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

The above, given the following input:

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable (SortOrder INT, FundType VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES
(9,  'DD'),
(2,  'DD'),
(4,  'FF'),
(22, 'BB'),
(11, 'FF')
```

produces this output:

```
FundType    GroupOrder
----------------------
BB          22
DD          2
FF          4
```

We can use now this `CTE` to sort by *group order*, then by the `SortOrder`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  ... cte statements here
)
SELECT m.*
FROM CTE AS c
INNER JOIN #mytable AS m ON c.FundType = m.FundType
ORDER BY GroupOrder, SortOrder
```

**Output:**

```
SortOrder   FundType
--------------------
2           DD
9           DD
4           FF
11          FF
22          BB
```